# Copy EventHandler in inherited class

Tags: c#, wpf, inotifypropertychanged

I'm developing an application in c# WPF.

I use a class `PropertyChangedNotifier` to manage INotifyPropertyChanged (see [that link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38896344/best-way-to-notify-property-change-when-field-is-depending-on-another)).

I use a classical ViewModelBase :

```
public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged, IRequestClose
{
    public PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = _propertyChanged;

        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

In my `MainViewModel : ViewModelBase` I have a `PropertyChangedNotifier<MainViewModel>` working like this :

```
class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private PropertyChangedNotifier<MainViewModel> _notifier;
    public new event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged
    {
        add { _notifier.PropertyChanged += value; }
        remove { _notifier.PropertyChanged -= value; }
    }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        _notifier = new PropertyChangedNotifier<MainViewModel>(this);
    }

    protected new void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        _notifier.OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
    }
}
```

But changes are not detected, when a value changes, my MainWindows doesn't refresh (without using PropertyChangedNotifier it works). I saw that system initiates windows by using `WindowsBase.dll!System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventManager.StartListening(object source)` and then I saw that my ViewModelBase.PropertyChanged is not null when the constructor for MainViewModel is called.

Is it possible to make something like this :

```
public MainViewModel()
{
    _notifier = new PropertyChangedNotifier<MainViewModel>(this);
    _notifier.PropertyChanged = base.PropertyChanged;
}
```

And will that fix my bug ?

Edit:

PropertyChangeNotifier from link :

```
[AttributeUsage( AttributeTargets.Property )]
public class DepondsOnAttribute : Attribute
{
    public DepondsOnAttribute( string name )
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public string Name { get; }
}

public class PropertyChangedNotifier<T> : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public PropertyChangedNotifier( T owner )
    {
        mOwner = owner;
    }

    public void OnPropertyChanged( string propertyName )
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if( handler != null ) handler( mOwner, new PropertyChangedEventArgs( propertyName ) );

        List<string> dependents;
        if( smPropertyDependencies.TryGetValue( propertyName, out dependents ) )
        {
            foreach( var dependent in dependents ) OnPropertyChanged( dependent );
        }
    }

    static PropertyChangedNotifier()
    {
        foreach( var property in typeof( T ).GetProperties() )
        {
            var dependsOn = property.GetCustomAttributes( true )
                                    .OfType<DepondsOnAttribute>()
                                    .Select( attribute => attribute.Name );

            foreach( var dependency in dependsOn )
            {
                List<string> list;
                if( !smPropertyDependencies.TryGetValue( dependency, out list ) )
                {
                    list = new List<string>();
                    smPropertyDependencies.Add( dependency, list );
                }

                if (property.Name == dependency)
                    throw new ApplicationException(String.Format("Property {0} of {1} cannot depends of itself", dependency, typeof(T).ToString()));

                list.Add( property.Name );
            }
        }
    }

    private static readonly Dictionary<string, List<string>> smPropertyDependencies = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

    private readonly T mOwner;
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `PropertyChangedNotifier<T>` ? Why not simply implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` correctly yourself?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Especially when it *is already* implemented by inheritance from ViewModelBase. IMO, the question doesn't make sense.

Comment: PropertyChangedNotifier is used to create dependence between properties.  If I create a square, with height, width and perimeter, I can set `[DependsOn("height")]` on property perimeter. Like this when height changes, my PropertyChangedNotifier will raise a property change for both perimeter and height.

Comment: But you're not exposing that notifier? Publicly you're only exposing your implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged, why do you need the notifier class?

Comment: The notifier is in the link (see line 2). My question is just : How can I copy EventHandler form the upper class ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that when my `MainViewModel` is created, the `base.PropertyChanged` is null. The constructor is called, fields/properties initialized (some call OnPropertyChanged) and after the MainView.InitializeComponent() add a handler in `base.PropertyChanged` (I attached a debugger to see that). This adding is done in the `ViewModelBase`, ignoring the `public new event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged` in `MainViewModel`.

I've the idea to check if `base.PropertyChanged` has been modify and copy it.

I've done this, I don't know if there is a good idea, what do you think ?

```
public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged, IRequestClose
{
    protected event PropertyChangedEventHandler _propertyChanged;
    protected bool propertyAdded { get; private set; }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged
    {
        add
        {
            _propertyChanged += value;
            propertyAdded = true;
        }
        remove { _propertyChanged -= value; }
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = _propertyChanged;

        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    public Delegate[] Get_PropertyChanged()
    {
        isPropertyAdded = false;
        Delegate[] delegates = new Delegate[0];
        if (_propertyChanged != null)
        {
            delegates = _propertyChanged.GetInvocationList();
            _propertyChanged = null;
        }

        return delegates;
    }
}
```

and

```
class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private PropertyChangedNotifier<MainViewModel> _notifier;
    public new event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged
    {
        add { _notifier.PropertyChanged += value; }
        remove { _notifier.PropertyChanged -= value; }
    }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        _notifier = new PropertyChangedNotifier<MainViewModel>(this);
    }

    protected new void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (isPropertyAdded)
        {
            foreach (Delegate d in Get_PropertyChanged())
            {
                _notifier.PropertyChanged += (PropertyChangedEventHandler)d;
            }
        }

        _notifier.OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a convoluted solution to a simple `NotifyPropertyChanged("dependentProperty")`, although I do understand the desire to engineer fancy solutions. It would make sense if it had some performance/loc benefits, but it doesn't. It just adds complexity.